# shell script(calculate the division of two variables taking from a file)

Tags: shell

I would like to divide two numbers which were extracted from a file using the below commands

```
temp1= grep PERM_ALLOCATED_SIZE /log/health_eg/DBsize.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' '
temp2= grep PERM_IN_USE_SIZE /log/health_eg/DBsize.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' '
```

and I'm able to print this

```
251658240
16239740
```

`temp1` and `temp2` respectively but I could not able to perform division for the above..

Sample output:

```
temp=temp2/temp1(0.064)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Try using AWK: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=awk%20bash%20calc

Comment: I think you're looking for the `bc` command. e.g. `printf "%0.3f" $(bc -l <<<'16239740 / 251658240')`

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is using `echo` and `bc -l`:

```
echo "251658240/16239740" | bc -l
```

Output:

```
15.49644514013155383029
```

Using your example, you can do that:

```
temp=`echo $temp2/$temp1*0.64 | bc -l`
```

Comment: Jacques Hi Marcel Actually I could not able to perform the division of the respective variables properly as It is taking some junk values and displaying irrelavant output. Can you suggest me something on this..Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Did you try to use bc as I have shown? Could you paste your code?